# Amp-Story non-configured provider

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

I am working on creating an amp-story and would like my share providers to include non-configured providers, but I can't create an endpoint because the bookend gets parsed and puts it as data-param rather than data-share. Anybody have a work around?

Bookend

```
{
  "provider": "reddit",
  "share-endpoint": "https://www.reddit.com/submit"
}
```

Generated Amphtml

```
<amp-social-share 
     width="48" 
     height="66" 
     class="i-amphtml-story-share-icon i-amphtml-element i-amphtml- 
           notbuilt amp-notbuilt i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml- 
           layout-size-defined i-amphtml-error i-amphtml-element-error" 
     type="reddit" 
     data-param-share-endpoint="https://www.reddit.com/submit" 
     style="width: 48px; height: 66px;" 
     error-message="The data-share-endpoint attribute is required. amp- 
           social-share​​​">
</amp-social-share>
```

EDIT: Made it more readable

Comment: OP has filed a [feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/19284) for this as well, which may contain more up-to-date information